# How to enable code completion in PhpStorm only with Tab key

Tags: phpstorm

How to enable code completion in PhpStorm only with <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, and other keys (e.g. <kbd>Enter</kbd>) should be disabled? Can't find this option in settings.

The problem is in the conflict between code completion and live templates. They both use the same shortcuts('tab' and 'enter'). I don't know why. How to separate them?

Comment: Remember: these are two different actions: the TAB replaces the current code with the selected option and the ENTER inserts the selected option.

Comment: @Dirk McQuickly So you mean it's unconfigurable?

Comment: It's configurable -- you can swap shortcuts around .. or just remove a shortcut from one of the. It's just that both of them are used depending on context. In brand new code `Enter` is better while when editing existing code `Tab` is much more convenient.

Comment: @LazyOne How to remove 'enter'?

Comment: Find the rigth action and use "Remove Shortcut" from context menu -- `Settings/Preferences | Keymap` -- it has `Find action by shortcut` functionality (a button next to local search field). So you just search what actions has `Enter` as a shortcut -- it should be no problem finding the right one from found results.

Comment: I wonder what the problem is? If you don't need the ENTER, don't use it?

Comment: @LazyOne Cool! Enter key stoped working at all.

Comment: *"The problem is in the conflict between code completion and live templates"* Sounds like you have selected an `Enter` to be a Expand key for Live Templates; or... you actually complete live template entry in code completion popup. Without knowing more details I cannot suggest "proper" resolution (except what you have already did -- disabled `Enter` for code completion).

Comment: @LazyOne Yes i used 'Enter' for live templates. You're right. Indeed, for live templates I can use 'space'. Thank you so much for that idea!

Comment: What I was trying to really say -- it should not be an issue in general. I mean -- I'm using default `Tab` for Live Template s.. and it does not stop me from using `Tab` in code completion. In Code Completion popup the exact Live Template abbreviation will be selected over the actual variable/method/class. Maybe your usage pattern/habits are different -- at the end of the day I'm using PhpStorm since v0.5 or so on daily basis and got used to it and having no issues in this regard. New users/other people may have different opinions on that, of course.

Answer (score 5):

Completing code items can be configured via "Choose Lookup Item" actions in Settings\Preferences | Keymap:

[image: keymap - lookup]

Change or remove the assigned shortcut as @LazyOne suggested.

You can also change the key to expand live templates with:

[image: templates - change key]

So you can eventually configure this in any way you want.